# Python noob here: On a Python enabled web server, how do I use Python?

Tags: python, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

My goal is to replace PHP with Python.  I'm pretty good with PHP and I can use Python on my own local machine, but I can't get it to work on my web server. My web host says they support Python, so I must be doing something wrong.

Now, Python is associated with CGI.  Do python files have to go into my cgi-bin folder? I've never seen a web file with a py extension or a cgi extension, I don't know how these things work, I'm really only familiar with PHP.

I watched the first hour of Google's "Learn Python" class and that only talks about running Python locally.

:(  Sorry I'm so nub, please fix me.

Comment: You'll have to use a framework like Django.

Comment: Why do I have to use a framework like Django?  I'm not arguing it's effectiveness, but why?  I use codeigniter and kohana for PHP, I'm fine with frameworks.  But why do I HAVE to use Django?

Comment: You don't HAVE to use Django (or any framework for that matter), but it will probably be a lot easier to work with than plain CGI. It also might be that your web host means they are running mod_python or similar, and then you really want to be using a framework.

Comment: I would keep working through learning the Python language. It's remarkably expressive and IMHO a serious step up from something like PHP. I would recommend Flask if you're deadset on jumping into web development. But I would really suggest keeping up learning the language -- before you know it you may be writing web frameworks of your own...!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a perfectly acceptable CGI script. If you are using Apache, it will need to go into your cgi-bin, need to be executable (I may be wrong on this), and you should name it with the common extension for the language `.py`, or with `.cgi`.

If you can control what files your webserver will consider CGI, you can place the file wherever you want. Chances are, you can't control that. You can view more information on CGI in Apache here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

The basic gist is that Apache will not treat a file as a CGI file unless two conditions are met: The `cgi-script` will need to be activated using the `AddHandler` or `SetHandler` directives, and `ExecCGI` will need to be enabled in the `Options` directive. Typically, this is not available to the user in a shared hosting environment.

EDIT: To clarify, CGI is just a mechanism for you to write scripts in any arbitrary language, and have your webserver execute them and send the output from that script to your clients. It's not a recommended approach for anything but a simple script, due to the fact that on every single request the server will fire up a new instance of your interpreter. For Python, the best solution would be a [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi) compatible framework, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/page/start), or [Django](http://djangoproject.com). The first two are micro-frameworks that try to stay out of your way, while Django is a full-stack framework that provides a whole lot of glue.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will look into what you said further. As much as I hear "Forget PHP, use Python instead," I can't seem to find hardly any beginner-friendly documentation for replacing PHP with Python.

Comment: I think it's partly due to the way mod_php works in Apache. You can just write some PHP in your HTML and It Just Works, whereas the same doesn't really apply with Python. I would recommend looking into a Python micro-framework that abstracts some of the details out without forcing you into too many decisions, such as Flask or Bottle.

Answer (score 2):

The Python way to do web applications has more in common with something like CodeIgniter or Cake PHP.

Start with [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com), just try the tutorial. The most common complaint about Django from die-hard PHP developers is that Django will not let you mix code and HTML - and it IS a good thing.

Of course you can do plain old CGI, but it is the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your web hosting company, the #!/usr/bin/env python  line may need to read a bit differently.  Some include a version number on "python" and some have python in a different directory.  You'll need to check with your provider.

Also, you need to give the world execute (NOT write) permission on the file, since you are WANTING people to execute the script.

What happens now if you upload that code with a .cgi or .py extension in your cgi-bin folder and then go to it in your browser?

Also, if you google "python cgi" you'll find a lot of tutorials.  For simple stuff without tons of hits, cgi will work fine, although as others have said, there are other mechanisms that are far more resource efficient when that's needed.

You can't mix python and html on the same page, but there are mechanisms  (see python and server side include or SSI) for writing an html page with a placemark that calls your python program and puts the response from the python program there in the resulting displayed html.